# Using subdomain to setup domain

Tags: subdomain

I am trying to migrate a site to a new server (centOS5 and plesk 9.2.1)

I would like to get the site running on a subdomain before pointing the root domain to the new server.

In plesk I created example.com and the subdomain setup.example.com and then I pointed setup.example.com to my new server. That works.

plesk setup folders as follows:

- example.com/
- example.com/httpdocs/
- example.com/subdomains/
- example.com/subdomains/setup/
- example.com/subdomians/setup/httpdocs

At the moment, setup.domain.com shows the index file in example.com/subdomains/setup/httpdocs

I would like setup.example.com to serve the files out of example.com/httpdocs

Here is what I have tried.
- using a server alias in plesk instead of a subdomain
- using a subdomain, then modifying setup.example.com's DocumentRoot in httpd.include to be example.com/httpdocs and restarting apache

I've searched everywhere, is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. It was actually quite easy. I am just dumb. I'm posting my "solution" (if you can call it that) in case another noob is having the same problem.

I created the DomainAlias setup.domain.com and enabled the local DNS service. Done.

Note: When I created the domain alias, I disabled synchronizing the DNS zone, because I didn't want the subdomain (setup.domain.com) to be pointed to the old server, which is currently serving domain.com

Comment: +1 for following up your own question with an answer for future people with this problem